# How to make lasting changes to config.xml in Ionic project

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

[Following Google Firebase's instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova) (step 7) I'm trying to add the following to my config.xml file (in an Ionic project):

```
<universal-links>
    <host name="abc123.app.goo.gl" scheme="https" />
    <host name="my-app.firebaseapp.com" scheme="https">
        <path url="/__/auth/callback"/>
    </host>
</universal-links>
```

But each time I emulate the app the inserted code gets removed. How can I add the required code to the config.xml and keep it there without Ionic (or Cordova) removing the modifications.

Comment: Are you editing `config.xml` in the root of the project (alongside `www`) or a deep copy somewhere under `platforms/`?

Comment: In the project root folder

Comment: hmm, it should not drop XML tags in the root `config.xml` unless they are inside comments (comments get stripped when cordova processes the XML).

Comment: Well, it gets removed nonetheless. For now it is not important anymore since I dropped the use of Firebase as it didn't solve my use case. Thanks for your replies though!

Comment: @Ben were you able to find a solution to this? I am not using firebase by the way

Comment: Only thing that worked for me was to remove platform, make changes to config.xml and then add the platform back. `ionic cordova platform rm android` , `ionic cordova platform add android`

Comment: I realise this is an old question, but none of the comments here or on the selected answer _actually_ clarify this properly: when an Ionic Cordova project is launched for development with live-reload, the `config.xml` is backed up, then the active file is modified with a custom `<access origin="..." />` element.. _after_ you stop the live-reload process, your `config.xml` backup is restored. that is why it appears to not persist changes in this scenario, there's no need to explicitly "clean" your project or remove/re-add platforms for this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the simple solution for this is to run a `cordova clean` before running any further ionic build/run.

1. Make your /config.xml changes
2. Run `cordova clean`
3. Run your ionic command (which rebuilds the config within platforms) like `ionic cordova run android`

I often run it as a concatenated command if I'm experimenting with config.xml, ie `cordova clean; ionic cordova run android;`

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, but this works great. Thanks a lot! (Came here to find my own question again when facing the same issue on another app ;)) +1A